# In the Browser dev tools in console the output is different after refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, brave-browser

I'm currently learning javascript. Therefore I'm often in the Brwoser's dev tool, in the console tab. Now there is something that I can't explain. The output in the console log is different after refreshing the webpage. Either it is like the upper window in my screenshot or like the lower window. In Chrome it is always like in the upper window.
In Brave browser the chance is about 50/50 that it is like the upper or lower.

I have found out that the option "preserve log" change the output so that it is always like the upper screenshot. But I would like to turn off this option to get a cleared console after a refresh.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior of the browser?

I'm working on macOS 12.0.1 Monterey and
Brave Broser: Version 1.32.106 Chromium: 96.0.4664.45 (Offizieller Build) (x86_64)
or
Chrome: Version 96.0.4664.55 (Offizieller Build) (x86_64)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that logs to the console?

Comment: Thank you. The code is

`"use strict";`
`let jumbo = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");`
`console.log(jumbo);`

Comment: Sorry I have a little formatting problems. As I don't know mini-Markdown yet.
However. The site is reacheable with this
[link](https://js.miracuru.ch/Uebungsordner/Document%20Object%20Model%20I/1%20BSI/)

Comment: I would say it's most likely because the console hasn't rendered the element at the time of the log. Not too sure though.

Comment: Thank you @skara9. That would clarify.
I had a guess that it could depend on loading time or render time. But it was more a vague guess. Think then I can't do much about this. Just reload a few times until the correct output is visible.

Comment: Yes it has definitively something to do with load / render time.
I have written a small timeout and now it loads everytime perfectly.

`
let jumbo = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
let timeoutID = window.setTimeout("console.log(jumbo);", 500);
` @skara9

Comment: Yeah, I was about to suggest that. Great that it works :)

Comment: I use brave as well. came up to this situation, just hit refresh and it started showing normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share the solution to my problem.
Now I'm a few lessons further in my course and got new commands.
With the load EventListener it works:

```
let jumbo

window.addEventListener("load", e => {
    jumbo = document.querySelector(".jumbotron");
    console.log(jumbo);
});
```

The teacher mentioned also that there are also two other parameter or commands: "async" and "defer".

Answer (score 0):

Click the gear in the top right corner of the console panel to show options. Untick "Preserve log".
[image]

Comment: Thank you.
"Preserve log" is already unticked. And still shows this behavior.

Comment: I tried it also with a factory reset of all options, without success.